# Versioning services

Tags: microservices, azure-service-fabric

We are trying to do Microservices with MS' ServiceFabric.

The scenario:
We have a Service1 running version1 and getting ready to upgrade to v2.

Three other services depend on the interface of Service1. We want to be able to release v2 of Service1, but keep v1 running until we have upgraded and tested the three services against v2.

All the examples I have found, v2 replaces v1 immediately. Can this be configured? And is there a method to tell the service discovery mechanism that I rely on a specific version of a given service?

Answer (score 2):

The application upgrade workflow will, as you mention, replace v1 with v2.  However, if you wish for v1 and v2 to coexist for some time (to allow you to do testing, gradually route some users to the new version, etc.) you can accomplish this with a slightly more involved workflow:

1. Provision and create a new service instance with version v2.
2. Perform your testing against this instance (v2).
3. Once you are satisfied with the testing, point your dependent services at the new instance (v2).
4. Once the v1 instance is no longer being used, delete it.

This of course may give you extra headaches due to needing to manage this process yourself, deal with your dependency chains, et cetera.  That's the tradeoff- if you want more control of the upgrade/rollout process, you necessarily have to handle more details yourself.

Alternatively, you can look into standing up a "staging" cluster where you can deploy and test new versions of your services without impacting your production services, and only roll the deployments out to your production cluster once they have been verified in stage.  Some of our customers have gone this route, as it makes the deployment and verification workflow much simpler at the cost of additional resources.

Comment: It just seems somewhat risky, given that it is manual - we have to essentially give the service a new name everytime we upgrade it - and the risk of forgetting that is way too high. EDIT: Oh - and this will cause ripple-effects - other services will be dependant on the three updated services and so on...

Comment: Indeed, the more control you need and the more complex your dependency chains are, the bigger ops headache you will have.  I believe the simplest (though most expensive) model is to have multiple clusters, allowing your production services to be unaffected until the new deployments have been fully verified.  As I've added to the answer, some customers use a staging cluster to verify their deployments in an environment very similar to production.  Large teams often will employ additional test clusters as well, to add multiple levels to their staging process (with increasing level of stability).

Comment: @Goblin what we are doing for those cases is injecting version name in our service url like service/v1/blabla. service/v2/blabla. After we release v2 we are planning a sunset for service-v1. Until that time we are keeping both service up. We are monitoring the usage of service-v1 and making necessary reminders and closing v1. I am not sure what kind of services you are providing and how many different clients are consuming your services but if you need backward-compatibility and smooth transition that seems the only way.

Comment: @cool That's exactly what we want :-) Are you hosting both versions in the same codebase? We were thinking of doing immutable services, but that isn't really an option as far as I can figure in service fabric

Comment: @Goblin Well I don't know anything about ServiceFabric. But yes we are hosting both version in the same codebase.